# Google Maps causing browser to run out of memory

Tags: javascript, google-maps

This is somewhat of a novice question.

I have a Google Map (APIv3) in a webpage. Every 60 seconds, I want it to query my database and draw circles on the map based on the database activity. I've gotten this to work, but after 10 minutes, the browser will crash and say it run out of memory (it's a crappy LG Smart TV browser). I know the issue, but I don't know how to solve it.

I'm calling the "initializeMap" function over and over, but all the older instances of the map are staying behind in memory. Is there a way that I can initialize once, but then clear/load the circles every 60 seconds?

Here's my code as it stands today. Many thanks in advance!

```
var citymap = {};

function initializeMap() {
   loadMap(); // This is the database call that fills citymap[] with information
   var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 4
   };
   delete map;
   var circleArray =[];
   for (var i = 0; i < circleArray.length; i++ ) {
             circleArray[i].setMap(null);
   }
   circleArray.length = 0;        
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    for (var city in citymap) {
    var populationOptions = {
       strokeColor: '#FA6A42',
       strokeOpacity: 0,
       strokeWeight: 0,
       fillColor: '#FA6A42',
       fillOpacity: .8,
       map: map,
       center: citymap[city].center,
       radius: 135000 + (citymap[city].num_entries * 10000)
    };
    cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
 }
}
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load', initializeMap);

function refreshData() {
   window.setInterval(function () {
      initializeMap();
      }, 60000);
}
```

Comment: just move the markers, don't redo the whole dang map...

Comment: Your `for` loop does nothing because before it there is `var circleArray =[];`